# how save image to folder from Image control Win 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8

I have a Image control

```
       <Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="400" Margin="499,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>
```

And I capture photo from Camera

```
        private async void TakePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
        camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);

        var photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo != null)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
            img.Source = image;
        }
    }
```

And now I want to save this image from img control to folder, but I don't know how decode image from img control to StorageFile

```
        private async void SaveFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("jpeg image", new List<string>() { ".jpeg" });
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New picture";

        StorageFile ff = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (ff != null)
        {
            await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(ff);
        }
    }
```

this is a save method, which i want to save image from Image control

Answer (score 2):

The
`var photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);` returns a StorageFile. All you have to do is save it to the location you want.

You can accomplish this in may ways.

Example:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; // the app's local storage folder


await photo.MoveAsync(localFolder); //move the file to a new location
```

2.

```
//Create a new copy in a new location

await photo.CopyAsync(localFolder);
```

**Note** that `var photo == StorageFile photo`. This means that the after the photo was captured, a copy of it was already saved to a temporary location(The App's TempState directory) on the local storage.

Comment: but i want to save this image from another method which i can't access to var photo

Comment: you can make the photo variable public static in the class and access it anywhere.